Error tokenizing data when merging multiple csv into one excel file
I'm having an issue regarding on Error tokenizing data.
I'm trying to merge multiple csv files into one excel file and my files have some special characters in it with big data.
This is the error I get:
Could not read file sept_.csv because of error: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 16 fields in line 4, saw 20

Could not read file oct.csv because of error: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 16 fields in line 4, saw 20 

Could not read file aug_.csv because of error: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 16 fields in line 4, saw 20

here the code.
import pandas as pd
import os

# replace with your folder's path
folder_path = r'C:\Users\Documents\Test'
all_files = os.listdir(folder_path)
# Filter out non-CSV files
csv_files = [f for f in all_files if f.endswith('.csv')]
# Create a list to hold the dataframes
df_list = []
for csv in csv_files:
    file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, csv)
    try:
        # Try reading the file using default UTF-8 encoding
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        df_list.append(df)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        try:
            # If UTF-8 fails, try reading the file using UTF-16 encoding with tab separator
            df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='\t', encoding='utf-16', error_bad_lines=False)
            df_list.append(df)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Could not read file {csv} because of error: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Could not read file {csv} because of error: {e}")
# Concatenate all data into one DataFrame
big_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
# Save the final result to a new CSV file
big_df.to_csv(os.path.join(folder_path, 'combined_file.csv'), index=False)

I tried changing to encoding, sep and adding error_bad_lines=False, but still giving me the same error.
Data:
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P               
9/30/2024 23:58 ANT ANT A   NO  TW3M02  SR_RX_S_P   SR_H_1  2873    BOARD   1   PASS    0   0   TAKT    8               
9/30/2024 23:58 ANT ANT A   NO  TW3M023 SR_RX_S_P   SR_H_1  2873    BOARD   1   PASS    0   0   GOOD                    
9/30/2024 23:58 ANT ANT A   NO  TW3M024 SR_RX_S_P   SR_H_1  2873    BOARD   1   PASS    0   0   ATTRIBUTES  6562    3324    2861    11.5L   0.9
9/30/2024 23:58 ANT ANT A   NO  TV2K124 SR_RX_S_P   SR_H_1  2873    BOARD   1   PASS    0   0   TAKT    8.4             
9/30/2024 23:58 ANT ANT A   NO  TV2K124 SR_RX_S_P   SR_H_1  2873    BOARD   1   PASS    0   0   GOOD                    
9/30/2024 23:58 ANT ANT A   NO  TV2K12  SR_RX_S_P   SR_H_1  2873    BOARD   1   PASS    0   0   ATTRIBUTES  6562    3324    2861    10.8R   0.9
9/30/2024 23:58 ANT ANT A   NO  TW3L024 SR_RX_S_P   SR_H_1  2873    BOARD   1   PASS    0   0   TAKT    15              


How does line 4 look like? Does it contain commas or quotation marks?

Without being able to see the CSV content it's hard to say what the problem might be. Show the first 4 lines from either of the problematic CSV files

Without the CSV content, we cannot help you, only tell you the exact same thing the error does.

i can say it contain colon, underscore, slash, quotation marks and period.

@noelfeng You seem to be averse to helping us to help you. Why is that?

@SIGNUP Sorry, I can't disclose any data due to confidential, I can describe it.

@noelfeng You can sanitize the data

@SIGNUP I added picture on the data and what inside the cell too

@noelfeng The CSV files are being processed as text - not images or Excel files. Show the [sanitised] text

@SIGNUP is it something like this?

Make a [mcve].  The data shown looks no different between lines 2-4 and per error message should have 16 fields but saw 20.  Give us a few lines of the exact data, when run with your code, produce the exact error.  Change any data that is confidential, but make sure it still produces the problem.

@MarkTolonen i added the properly data and did some edit, i hope this example is better. sorry everyone.

It is clear that the CSV is malformed. You have 16 columns (A-P) but an apparently variable number of tokens in the data lines
